# Easy Ways Of Finding Both Front And Side Profiles for Character Modelling

Tags: modeling

I'm starting to get into photorealistic character modelling and I'm trying to find some reference photos on the internet to practice with. Unfortunately I'm not having any luck finding any photos of the side view of people's faces, as most of the images on Google are of the front view. Does anyone have any tips or know of any websites I can visit to find both front and side views of the same person?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resources for Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender)

Answer (score 0):

It is probably simply a question of finding a suitable keyword combination. I tried both on Google Images and on Pinterest with "face front side" and found a lot of examples, both male and female. Furthermore, once found a good image, you can use the function to show similar ones, and you will have plenty of examples to practice.

Comment: I can find plenty of front view pictures, but I'm having almost zero luck finding side view pictures of either real people or cartoon characters. I'll try fiddling around with keywords a bit and see if I get anything promising. Right now I'm just using "[person name] face side view," which doesn't seem to be working

Answer (score 0):

I tried 'woman orthographic face views' and that yielded some results, 'man orthographic face views' works too. Really depends on what you're looking for, though!